# conditionally ignore rows load data mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, load-data-infile

I am loading a large data set (60 gigs) into a database. There are some records that can be skipped because they contain values that are missing.  How do I tell MySQL to skip rows that contain certain (missing in this case) values?  For example, my file looks like this

```
Value1, Value2
1,2
3,4
,5
9,10
```

The third row can be skipped and not loaded. I know that I can load everything and then just delete it but processing a 60 gig file takes a long time so I want to save on the computing power.

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: I am loading using the load data command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a trigger on the before insert on the table which checks if the particular field is null

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- condition to check
    IF NEW.Value1 is null THEN
       set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert a null value
                  in trigger_test: ', cast(new.Value1 as char));
   signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END$$
```

then run your Load data command

Comment: thank you for answering, could you please explain what a trigger does? i am not familiar with this concept.  your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The above trigger, checks before each insert on the table if the value is null then row is not inserted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me; instead none of my rows are inserted; I have posted this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595441/mysql-trigger-to-skip-certain-rows-during-load

Answer (score 5):

If 'Value1' is a unique field, then you can play with an IGNORE option. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  Value1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Value2 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Value1)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' 
  IGNORE -- forces to ingore existed records
  INTO TABLE table1
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 lines
  (@var1, Value2)
  SET Value1 = IF(@var1 = 0, 1, @var1)
```

'IF(@var1 = 0, 1, @var1)' helps us to change missing values '0' with EXISTED KEY VALUE '1', and these records will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue, you just need to add IGNORE to your statement.

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load-data-infile/

Comment: that SQL does not look as if it is anything to do with the example in the question. Would you like to update it to be applicable to the question?